# Flask template and CSS :hover pseudo class works for button, but :after and :visited pseudo classes don't

Tags: html, css

I've got some CSS where `:hover` pseudo class highlights the buttons as designed, but `:after` and `:visited` do nothing. The buttons otherwise function correctly.

Everything I've found in my research is about the reverse problem, so what's wrong with my code? I tried a few things and they're listed below.

As an aside, I couldn't get `var(--main-color)` to be recognized when I defined it in `:root`.

Nothing I found said it was reserved, but it wouldn't work for me.

The HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button id="Download" onclick="window.location.href = '{{ url_for('download_shelf_func') }}';"> Download A Shelf </button>
    <button id="Export" onclick="window.location.href = '{{ url_for('export_shelf_func') }}';"> Export A Shelf </button>  
    <button id="Home" onclick="window.location.href = '{{ url_for('index') }}';"> Return Home </button>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
:root {
    --primary-bg-color: #242c3a;
    --primary-color: #87abe5;
    --container-bg-color: #0a355b; 
    --highlight-color: #c3cbeb;
    --landing-color: #7da5e0;
}

.btn-group {
    position:relative;
}

.btn-group button {
    color: var(--primary-bg-color);
    background-color: var(--primary-bg-color);
    border: 1px solid var(--primary-bg-color);
    vertical-align: top;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: .8em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
    
.btn-group button:after, button:visited {
    background-color: var(--landing-color);
}

.btn-group button:hover {
    background-color: var(--highlight-color);
}
```

**Tried:**

#1: (individual selectors)

```
button:visited {
    background-color: var(--landing-color);
}

.btn-group button:after {
    background-color: var(--landing-color);
}

.btn-group button:hover {
    background-color: var(--highlight-color);
}
```

#2: (double colon)

```
.btn-group button::after {
    background-color: var(--landing-color);
}
```

#3: (different order)

```
.btn-group button:hover {
    background-color: var(--highlight-color);
}

button:visited {
    background-color: var(--landing-color);
}

.btn-group button:after {
    background-color: var(--landing-color);
}
```

Comment: Actually, turns out this is a duplicate, only different phrasing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625290/flask-make-a-button-direct-to-another-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:visited` pseudo class works only with `<a>` elements that have the `href` attribute. Because `<button>` elements are not used to jump the user to a different webpage but mostly to execute a piece of JavaScript code, it doesn't work here.

As your buttons are used to link the user somewhere, change them to `<a>` elements:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <a id="Download" href="{{ url_for('download_shelf_func') }}" target="self"> Download A Shelf </a>
    <a id="Export" href="{{ url_for('export_shelf_func') }}" target="self"> Export A Shelf </a>  
    <a id="Home" href="{{ url_for('index') }}" target="self"> Return Home </a>
</div>
```

**Don't forget to change CSS selectors to match `a` elements instead of `button` ones!**

---

The `::after` pseudo class (note the double colon) is used to insert a piece of content **after** an element. To make it visible, you have to add `content` rule to it and specify `width` and `height` too.

*Note that `100%` used with `::after` pseudo class means the entire width of the button (the parent element) and not the document*

```css
button::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

I'm not sure what did you want to do with the `::after` pseudo class, but here you go, it works.

Comment: That's a helpful answer for a Flask template redirect, but a FreeCodeCamp article says a `button:hover` pseudo-class selector can by styled: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-button-style-hover-color-and-background/

I assume that means an `onclick()` javascript call would have to do it?

Comment: @MeghanM. `:hover` provides an override style for the element. Styles apply when user hovers the element.

Comment: Oops! The `button:hover` styling works for my code. It's the `:visited` pseudo-class that does not. So would the `onclick(someJavascript)` have to take of the `button:visited` state?

Comment: @MeghanM. It has nothing to do with the **click** event. It's applied when user **hovers** over an element.

Answer (score 2):

The :visited CSS pseudo-class applies once the link has been visited by the user. For privacy reasons, the styles that can be modified using this selector are very limited. The :visited pseudo-class applies only to  and  elements that have an href attribute.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why but not how to produce the functionality. If JS is required, any pointers would be appreciated. I updated my title.